HSTS error due to substituted certificate
For about two months I have been unable to reach a website I frequent. Firefox displays this message:

Did Not Connect: Potential Security Issue
Firefox detected a potential security threat and did not continue to
xxxxx.com because this website requires a secure connection.
What can you do about it?
xxxxx.com has a security policy called HTTP Strict Transport Security
(HSTS), which means that Firefox can only connect to it securely. You
can’t add an exception to visit this site.
The issue is most likely with the website, and there is nothing you
can do to resolve it. You can notify the website’s administrator about
the problem.
Websites prove their identity via certificates. Firefox does not trust this site
because it uses a certificate that is not valid for xxxxx.com. The certificate is only > valid for the following names: *.a6z-dns.ovh, a6z-dns.ovh
Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN

When I view the certificate, I see this:

The website's certificate is not issued by "Certainly", and the name "a6z-dns.ovh" is not related to the domain.
This is on my primary workstation. It happens with any browser, even newly install browsers (Edit: Firefox, Chromium, Edge, Konqueror, Opera, Falkon, Midori.) There is not a problem viewing the website from inside a VM on my workstation and other machines/devices on the same network. (Edit: This is not a corporate environment and I do not use any OVH Cloud products or services.)
I've checked my DNS setup, rebooted the workstation, tried everything I can think of, but nothing helps. Does anybody have any idea what the problem might be?
Edit: More information based on comments below:
Software installs before the problem began: openSUSE updates, packman updates, plexmediaserver, antiword update from KDE-Extra, recoll update from KDE-Extra.
I have never even heard of OVH Cloud dns. The dns servers I use are 10.0.0.10 (my own server for private network) and google's servers.
I am not the owner or operator of the web server in question. I didn't give the name because the last time I posted this question it got moved to meta where everybody just said "It's not our problem". If you need to know, the website is stackoverflow.com. (And this revelation better not get this question moved to meta again!)
This is obviously something that only effects this one workstation.

You say it happens on every browser.  Does it happen with Firefox?  Unlike every other browser, Firefox uses the machine's certificate store. [Edit] your question to include enough information to answer your question. If you are using any OVH Cloud products or services, you should uninstall them.  If this is a corporate environment we really need to know as that changes potential diagnostic choices

@Ramhound see my edits above

Something on your system is performing potentially a malicious man in the middle attack on your HTTPS traffic.

Any idea how I can track down the culprit? I tried ss -ltnp and ss -lnp and didn't see anything questionable. I went into multi-user mode and killed off everything except systemd and wicked. Still have the problem.

I would backup my personal files and reinstall from a trusted source from an ISO I downloaded from another trusted machine

I reinstalled the OS and took two days to reconfigure everything. It's now working properly.

As the operator of the web server only allows secure connections, there are no configuration options on your site.
The operator has to fix his configuration.

The problem is the author's configuration. I can tell by the details of the author they likely have software they are using that is performing a man in the middle type of operation.  It most certainly is not malicious since OVH Cloud DNS is an intentional configuration. It also appears the author is the operator of the web server.

@Ramhound How can you tell? He doesn't tell us what site, so we don't know if the problem is global or local to him. Furthermore Certainly Intermediate R1 is in browsers trust stores, so it is not a MiTM software on his device... It is probably the default certificate returned by a load balancer because the domain requested is unknown to it. My guess is that the site is deleted from wherever it's hosted, but DNS not updated.

Additional information added to original post. Please let me know if you need any more info.

@vidarlo - Educated guess but I also research the .ovh domain, but the website that’s not working, absolutely is working. Just noticed the certificate is expired.
